# Django Model inheritance for efficient code

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance

I have a Django app that uses an Abstract Base Class ('Answer') and creates different Answers depending on the answer_type required by the Question objects. (This project started life as the Polls tutorial).  Question is now:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ANSWER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('CH', 'Choice'),
    ('SA', 'Short Answer'),
    ('LA', 'Long Answer'),
    ('E3', 'Expert Judgement of Probabilities'),
    ('E4', 'Expert Judgment of Values'),
    ('BS', 'Brainstorms'),
    ('FB', 'Feedback'),
    )
    answer_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                               choices=ANSWER_TYPE_CHOICES,
                               default='SA')
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="enter a question here")
```

And Answer is:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
"""
Answer is an abstract base class which ensures that question and user are
always defined for every answer
"""
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
class Meta:
    abstract = True
    ordering = ['user']
```

At the moment, I have a single method in Answer (overwriting get_or_update_answer()) with type-specific instructions to look in the right table and collect or create the right type of object.

```
    @classmethod
def get_or_update_answer(self, user, question, submitted_value={}, pk_ans=None):
    """
    this replaces get_or_update_answer with appropriate handling for all
    different Answer types. This allows the views answer and page_view to get
    or create answer objects for every question type calling this function.
    """
    if question.answer_type == 'CH':
        if not submitted_value:
            # by default, select the top of a set of radio buttons
            selected_choice = question.choice_set.first()
            answer, _created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(
                user=user,
                question=question,
                defaults={'choice': selected_choice})
        else:
            selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=submitted_value)
            answer = Vote.objects.get(user=user, question=question)
            answer.choice = selected_choice

    elif question.answer_type == 'SA':
        if not submitted_value:
            submitted_value = ""
            answer, _created = Short_Answer.objects.get_or_create(
                user=user,
                question=question,
                defaults={'short_answer': submitted_value})
        else:
            answer = Short_Answer.objects.get(
                user=user,
                question=question)
            answer.short_answer = hashtag_cleaner(submitted_value['short_answer'])
 etc... etc... (similar handling for five more types)
```

By putting all this logic in 'models.py', I can load user answers for a page_view for any number of questions with:

```
    for question in page_question_list:
        answers[question] = Answer.get_or_update_answer(user, question, submitted_value, pk_ans)
```

I believe there is a more Pythonic way to design this code - something that I haven't learned to use, but I'm not sure what. Something like interfaces, so that each object type can implement its own version of Answer.get_or_update_answer(), and Python will use the version appropriate for the object.  This would make extending 'models.py' a lot neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've shown, you're most of the way to reimplementing the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which is a pretty standard way of handling this sort of situation (you have a bunch of related subclasses, each needing its own handling logic, and want to iterate over instances of them and do something with each).

I'd suggest taking a look at how that pattern works, and perhaps implementing it more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I've revisited this problem recently, replaced one or two hundred lines of code with five or ten, and thought it might one day be useful to someone to find what I did here.

There are several elements to the problem I had - first, many answer types to be created, saved and retrieved when required; second, the GET vs POST dichotomy (and my idiosyncratic solution of always creating an answer, sending it to a form); third, some of the types have different logic (the Brainstorm can have multiple answers per user, the FeedBack does not even need a response - if it is created for a user, it has been presented.)  These elements probably obscured some opportunity to remove repetition, which make the visitor pattern quite appropriate.

### Solution for elements 1 & 2

A dictionary of question.answer_type codes that map to the relevant Answer sub-class, is created in views.py (because its hard to place it in models.py and resolve dependencies):

```
# views.py: 
ANSWER_CLASS_DICT = {
'CH': Vote,
'SA': Short_Answer,
'LA': Long_Answer,
'E3': EJ_three_field,
'E4': EJ_four_field,
'BS': Brainstorm,
'FB': FB,}
```

Then I can get the class of Answer that I want 'get_or_created' for any question with:

```
ANSWER_CLASS_DICT[question.answer_type]
```

I pass it as a parameter to the class method:

```
# models.py:
def get_or_update_answer(self, user, question, Cls, submitted_value=None, pk_ans=None):            
    if not submitted_value:
            answer, _created = Cls.objects.get_or_create(user=user, question=question)
    elif isinstance(submitted_value, dict):
            answer, _created = Cls.objects.get_or_create(user=user, question=question)
        for key, value in submitted_value.items():
                setattr(answer, key, value)
    else:
        pass
```

So the same six lines of code handles get_or_creating any Answer when submitted_value=None (GET) or not (submitted_value).

### Solution for element 3

The solution for element three has been to extend the model to separate at least three types of handling for users revisiting the same question:
  'S' - single, which allows them to record only one answer, revisit and amend the answer, but never to give two different answers.
  'T' - tracked, which allows them to update their answer every time, but makes the history of what their answer was available (e.g. to researchers.)
  'M' - multiple, which allows many answers to be submitted to a question.

Still bug-fixing after all these changes, so I won't post code.
Next feature: compound questions and question templates, so people can use the admin to screen to make their own answer types.